# Turn off caching of static files in Django development server

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, static-files, disable

**Is there an easy way to turn off caching of static files in Django's development server?**

I'm starting the server with the standard command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I've got `settings.py` configured to serve up static files from the `/static` directory of my Django project.  I've also got a middleware class that sets the `Cache-Control` header to `must-revalidate, no-cache` for development, but that only seems to affect URLs that are not in my `/static` directory.

Comment: Making this non-caching behavior the default was the subject of [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27572), and was deferred pending a possible merger with whitenoise (which has already solved this problem).

Comment: You could just test your sites in an [incognito window](https://www.quora.com/Does-incognito-mode-on-Chrome-use-the-cache-that-was-previously-stored). The caches won't be saved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you're using `django.views.static.serve`, it doesn't look like it - but writing your own view that just calls `django.views.static.serve`, adding the Cache-Control header should be rather easy.

Answer (score 21):

@Erik Forsberg's answer worked for me.  Here's what I had to do:

- Comment out the staticfiles app from `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = (
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.sites',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  )
  ```
- Leave my `STATIC_URL` variable set in `settings.py`:

  ```
  STATIC_URL = '/static/'
  ```
- Add an entry to my project's base `urls.py`:

  ```
  # static files w/ no-cache headers
  url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
      {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
  ```

Note that I'm also setting the `Cache-Control` headers in a middleware class `nocache.py`:

```
class NoCache(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        """
        set the "Cache-Control" header to "must-revalidate, no-cache"
        """
        if request.path.startswith('/static/'):
            response['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate, no-cache'
        return response
```

And then including that in `settings.py`:

```
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'nocache.NoCache',
    )
```

Comment: You can also do this without disabling the `staticfiles` app by starting the `runserver` command with the `--nostatic` option. This will prevent the `staticfiles` app from serving the static files. See my answer for more info.

Comment: One problem I saw with this approach is some apps like "rest framework" break when they have {% load staticfiles %} in their template files. Other than that, it fixed the problem of caching

Comment: Oddly enough, I couldn't get this to work. Firefox/Chrome seem to ignore the cache-control, the Django isn't sending back the right header. The only workaround I could find was to append a random number to the media's URL.

Comment: Quite complicated for something that should be added out of the box

Answer (score 20):

Django's `contrib.staticfiles` app automatically serves staticfiles for you by overriding the `runserver` command. With this configuration you can't control the way it serves the static files.

You can prevent the staticfiles app from serving the static files by adding the [`--nostatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver-nostatic) option to the runserver command:

```
./manage.py runserver --nostatic
```

Then you can write an url config to manually serve the static files with headers that prevent the browser from caching the response:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve as serve_static
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

urlpatterns = patterns('', )

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', never_cache(serve_static)),
    )
```

If you want your `manage.py runserver` command to have the `--nostatic` option on by default, you can put this in your `manage.py`:

```
if '--nostatic' not in sys.argv:
    sys.argv.append('--nostatic')
```

Comment: This is the simplest fix.

Comment: Seems a little strange that this is necessary; during development (the only time you should be using runserver according to recommendations) you don't really want things to cache do you? Seems to me that the default behavior during development should be to never_cache, and to make an optional argument that would turn on caching for runserver. Realize this isn't the place for Django suggestions, but it just struck me when researching this topic.

Comment: This answer won't always work. It can be simplified and made more generally useful. If `urlpatterns` includes a catch-all url at the end it will not work. So add the new url to the beginning of `urlpatterns`. And if you do not have `STATIC_URL` set to "static" it will not work. So use `urlpatterns = static(settings.STATIC_URL, view=never_cache(serve_static)) + urlpatterns`.  (The `static` function can be found in `django.conf.urls.static`.)

Comment: Certain `manage.py` commands don't recognize the `--nostatic` flag.  Updating `manage.py` to use and updated if statement of `if sys.argv[1] == 'runserver' and '--nostatic' not in sys.argv: ...` seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 14):

Use `whitenoise`.  There's a lot of issues with the static file serving in runserver and they're all already fixed in `whitenoise`.  It's also WAY faster.

They've [talked about just replacing the built-in static serving with it](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27572#comment:1), but no one has gotten around to it yet.

Steps to use it in development...

Install with `pip install whitenoise`

Add the following to the end of settings.py:

```py
if DEBUG:
    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    ] + MIDDLEWARE
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    ] + INSTALLED_APPS
```

Comment: 10 years has passed and still it is an issue. Should be top answer.

Answer (score 10):

My very simple solution:

```python
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

static_view = never_cache(serve)
urlpatterns += static_view(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                           document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Hmm.  This does not work for me.  I get this error: `TypeError: serve() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`.  Maybe you meant to use `django.conf.urls.static` instead?  Like: `urlpatterns = static(settings.STATIC_URL, view=never_cache(serve)) + urlpatterns`

Answer (score 9):

In newer versions of Django a very simple solution is modify the project urls like so:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_control
from django.conf import settings

# YOUR urlpatterns here... 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, view=cache_control(no_cache=True, must_revalidate=True)(serve))
```

I arrived at this by looking at how staticfiles modifies the urls automatically and just adding a view decorator.  I really don't understand why this isn't the default as this is for development ONLY.  The view is able to properly handle a "If-Modified-Since" HTTP header so a request is always made but contents are only transferred on changes (judged by looking at the modification timestamp on the file).

For this to work you **must** add `--nostatic` when using `runserver`, otherwise the above changes are simply ignored.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:** What I had before didn't work because I wasn't using `--nostatic` and the `never_cache` decorator also included `no-store` which meant unchanged files were always being re-transferred instead of returning `304 Not Modified`

Answer (score 1):

For newer Django, the way middleware classes are written has changed a bit.

Follow all the instructions from @aaronstacy above, but for the middleware class, use this:

```
class NoCache(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'must-revalidate, no-cache'
        return response
```

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple if you are using Django 2.0+

Step-1 : Make 'django.contrib.staticfiles' as comment in settings.py(Project level)

INSTALLED_APPS = [

```
# 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

Step-2 : Import followings in urls.py (Project level)

```
     from django.conf.urls.static import static

     from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve

     from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

     from . import settings
```

Step-3 : Add following line in urls.py(project level) after urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [

]

if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, view=never_cache(serve))
```

Make sure that STATIC_URL is declared in your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: This prevents Django from displaying any static files (images, css etc.)

Answer (score 0):

The staticfiles app implements serving of static files by [overriding the runserver command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py). We can do the same: override this command again and implement a custom handler which turns off caching.

Note that your django application must be before `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`, otherwise your command will be ignored.

```py
# your_django_app/management/commands/runserver.py

from django.utils.cache import add_never_cache_headers
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import (
    StaticFilesHandler as BaseStaticFilesHandler,
)
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver import (
    Command as RunserverCommand,
)


class StaticFilesHandler(BaseStaticFilesHandler):
    def serve(self, request):
        response = super().serve(request)
        add_never_cache_headers(response)
        return response


class Command(RunserverCommand):
    def get_handler(self, *args, **options):
        handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)

        # Check that serving static files is enabled
        if isinstance(handler, BaseStaticFilesHandler):
            # If yes, replace the original handler with our custom handler
            handler = StaticFilesHandler(handler.application)

        return handler
```

Answer (score 0):

With [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise), you can disable your browser to cache the static files of Django.

So first, install `whitenoise` as shown below:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then, you must set `whitenoise.runserver_nostatic` just before `django.contrib.staticfiles` in [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps) and set `WhiteNoiseMiddleware` just after [SecurityMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware) in [MIDDLEWARE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#middleware) in `settings.py` as shown below otherwise your browser still caches the static files in Django:

```py
# "settings.py"

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic', # Here
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # Here
    ...
]
```

Lastly, I recommend to clear browser's cache after setting `whitenoise` following my answer here because your browser will still keep the cache of the static files of Django. *On Google Chrome, you can open the page to clear cache with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> which also works on Firefox. Or you can empty cache and reload the page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Firefox). Or you can use the Google Chrome extension [Clear Cache](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn) to clear cache

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`never_cache`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache) decorator from `django.views.decorators.cache` to patch the default [`django.views.static.serve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/views/#django.views.static.serve).

For example, you could use this in your development settings file:

```py
import django.views.static
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

django.views.static.serve = never_cache(django.views.static.serve)
```

Answer (score -1):

This has nothing with Django, because nothing changed after I reinstall Django using pip.

This is the behavior of browser, so you just need to clear cached images files of your browser.

### Ref

[Chrome Clear cache and cookies](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Yeah but you don't wanna do that every few seconds