# Django: remove 'Vary: cookie' response header for static files

Tags: django, caching

I am using Django to serve static files (dev, localhost only). I want these files to be cached by the browser, but they aren't. I therefore added Middleware to change the response header for /static/ urls as described here [Turn off caching of static files in Django development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013735/turn-off-caching-of-static-files-in-django-development-server) (They were fixing the opposite issue, but also by changing the header).

The issue is that the files are still not being cached. I believe this is because of the 'Vary: Cookie' header. How do I get rid of this header? It seems to be added sometime after my Middleware StaticCache is executed.

Response header of static files in browser:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=315360000
Content-Length:319397
Content-Type:application/javascript
Date:Mon, 22 Aug 2016 13:34:04 GMT
Expires:Sun, 17-Jan-2038 19:14:07 GMT
Last-Modified:Fri, 19 Aug 2016 23:18:48 GMT
Server:WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.10
Vary:Accept-Encoding, Cookie
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    '<app>.middleware.BeforeViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    '<app>.middleware.StaticCache', 
    '<app>.middleware.ExceptionMiddleware',
)
```

middleware.py

```
class StaticCache(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if request.path.startswith('/static/'):
            response['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=315360000'
            response['Vary'] = 'Accept-Encoding'
            response['Expires'] = 'Sun, 17-Jan-2038 19:14:07 GMT'
        return response
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the `Vary: Cookie` header is set by the `SessionMiddleware`. Since the response middlewares run in reverse order, you should put your `StaticCache` middleware *before* the session middleware in your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: I have not tested this yet because I ended up solving it a different way (got default cache to work with static files), but will leave it here for others. Thanks!