# Static file changes are not reflected on browser refresh

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm new to Django and trying to figure out why the changes in static css and js files are not picked up by the browser.

Only after I run `python manage.py collectstatic` followed by restarting the server do I see the desired results.

Using Django 1.11 and python 2.7

Here is a glimpse of my `settings.py`

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


 # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [u'customizeittoday.herokuapp.com', u'localhost']
# Application definition


TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]




# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

#STATIC_URL = '/static/'



#static media settings
STATIC_URL = 'https://' + AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME + '.s3.amazonaws.com/'

MEDIA_URL = STATIC_URL + 'media/'

# STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), )

# STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS =    ('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder','django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',)
```

Comment: show your template

Comment: Can you specify the exact file?

Comment: hm, index.html, I guess? :)

Comment: please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013735/turn-off-caching-of-static-files-in-django-development-server

Comment: @seuling Tried those. Doesn't work at all.

Comment: are you in dev environment? then you haven't use `collectstatic` command. It's browser issue, not your settings. You have to remove cache when upload css/js cause your browser caching it.

Comment: For me, when developing, I use `Cmd - shift - R` for refresh cache. (with google chrome)

Answer (score 1):

This is old but I suspect this is because you are storing your static files on AWS S3. By default S3 uses a default `cache-control` header that specifies a 24 hour cache time.

You should probably migrate to using versioned static files.

You can use [ManifestStaticFilesStorage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage) which is designed to do this as part of the `collectstatic` cycle by appending hashes to filenames. By default it applies to all filetypes.

If you want to use it but want to specify which filetypes are versioned, then I wrote [an extension](https://github.com/TomAnthony/django-flexible-manifest-staticfiles) that allows you to whitelist / blacklist files by path pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes browser itself caches the CSS or js files and load them from the cache. To avoid that "**disable cache**" in the network tab of the developer console for the respective browser.