# Many HTTP 304 responses results in fewer GET requests

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-staticfiles, http-caching

I have a Django development server hosting a web-page that real-time (ish) displays information gathered from numerous servers I watch over. This web-page is still in development, so I am currently using the built-in web host provided with Django, started on an Ubuntu host with:

`python3 manage.py runserver IP:Port`

On the same ubuntu host there is a python script continuously reaching out to the monitored servers and formatting the responses into a .html file which the client reloads within a `<div>` every minute. The general functionality of the page the client accesses is as follows:

```
<div id="status" style="width:100%; height: 1000"></div>
<script>
    $('#status').load("{% static 'alerts/status.html' %}");
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#status').load("{% static 'alerts/status.html' %}");
    }, 60000);
</script>
```

...so the page loads the `status.html` file within the division on page-load, and then reloads it every minute. This has been working great, however, I have noticed looking at the Django log, that if status.html has not changed after ten status 304 (Not Modified) responses, the time waited between requests begins to roll-off. That is to say, instead of waiting 1 minute, it waits 2 minutes, then 5 minutes, and so on (roughly, I forget the actual rate of roll-off).

Now the issue I'm facing is that my server went down over the weekend (unrelated), but the display screen I had the web-page up on stayed active, so it rolled off so much that it seems it has completely broken, refusing to download the latest status.html, even when I force Chrome to reload everything and not use the cache (`ctrl + R` or `shift + F5`).

I tried researching this roll-off but couldn't find any information on it. I assume this is something built into Google Chrome (the browser I'm using) to save bandwidth when the page is not changing but my status page is a couple kilobytes at most and the 304 responses are already saving the little bandwidth that is so if there's a way to completely disable this roll-off for production that would be ideal.

In any case, any information on why I'm seeing this behavior / where it's coming from would be much appreciated as I can't seem to find any documentation on it. The closest thing I found was from Google's developer documentation on caching [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching). It mentions the ability to define maximum-age and no-cache behavior, so I could force the client to redownload status.html *every* minute, but this seems messy. While that would work in my specific scenario given status.html is a couple kilobytes at most, just disabling this roll-off behavior would do the trick *and* would keep unnecessary bandwidth down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the response for `status.html` doesn't have an explicit cache expiration header. In the absence of such a header, the browser is free to use its own algorithm (such as the roll-off you're seeing) to choose an expiration time. From [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.2):

> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times, a cache MAY assign a heuristic expiration time when an explicit time is not specified.... This specification does not provide specific algorithms.

So the solution is straightforward: assign an explicit cache expiration time.

Implementing this solution is unfortunately not trivial using Django's staticfiles app. A better default for this app would be to not cache the results at all, but that solution [was deferred](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27572) pending a merger with [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/).

Solutions include using a different server (like nginx); using a different app (like whitenoise); or using static views directly rather than the staticfiles app (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013735/turn-off-caching-of-static-files-in-django-development-server) for a few approaches).

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation. I decided, instead of fighting with Django and risking messing up my other views, to just disable the cache completely there with `$.ajaxSetup ({cache: false});` in the `<script>` in my question. My view is only a few kilobytes pulled once a minute so it's not worth the struggle to save bandwidth on. If I (or someone else) has this issue with a higher-bandwidth scenario the suggested solutions are very helpful though so I'm accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Page reload every 60 seconds
setInterval(function(){
    location.reload();
}, 60000);
```

Comment: I am having difficulties getting this to use the cache. I have reduced the update time to 2s for testing and added 'Expires' = '10' as a header to the django view for this page - I expected this to result in 5 status 304s before another status 200 but instead it is downloading status.html every time. Do you know what else I'm missing? I have also tried using `reload(false)` to be sure it shouldn't use cache.

Comment: Also - ideally I would only have to re-download status.html, this as-is downloads the whole page each time (so .css and .js files that aren't changing are now being re-downloaded when they don't have to). Is there any way to restrict this to the `<div>` in question?