# CSS class changed but the style is taking time to get applied

Tags: html, css, django

I added a new class in the custom CSS file in a Django app and changed the HTML accordingly.

The problem is that the `class` is getting applied to let's say a button but the page is not showing the changes.

For example:

Please check the below snippet

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Text</button>`

I added a new class .btn-custom in custom.css and changed the HTML file as well.

Now after the refresh, the above tag changed to

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn-lg">Text</button>`

But the style is not applied to the page.

I check the custom CSS file by opening the source and the changes I made are there.

After 2 to 3 hrs the changes getting reflected.
I tried hard refresh as well cache clearing and every other option related to cache

Comment: Did you check if the class styles are being overridden by another class?

Comment: Yes. Its not. Actually this class will get applied within 2-3 hrs.

Comment: This seems odd, if you can find `.btn-custom` in your stylesheet then its not a cache problem.

Comment: Yes. It's weird. Maybe something related to Django? I am new to Django.

Comment: I doubt it. Can you provide some code so I can take a closer look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior consists of your HTML being successfully changed but your CSS not changed. This indicates the presence of a cache. It can be either the browser cache or server-cache.

I see that you have ruled out caching issues, but from your description it seems that you have ruled out browser cache issues. However, Django has a [cache mechanism](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/) on its own, which caches static files. And the [cache of static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) [can be turned off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013735/turn-off-caching-of-static-files-in-django-development-server).

Comment: I tried clearing the Django cache. Still, it's the same.It has to be a cache issue. But I am not able to solve it.

Comment: @muneer it's also possible that you have some other server cache, like Cloudflare.

Comment: The app is in my local development environment

Comment: @muneer I advise you to conduct the following test: do a CSS change and take a look at the CSS file in your browser console sources tab. Is it refreshed at all?

Comment: Django cache clearing solved the issue. Earlier I didn't do it properly. Thanks for helping.